# Is this wall load bearing and if so what are options to eliminate?

Tags: load-bearing

[image: ground floor rec room]Trying to determine if wall between kitchen and family room can be removed.

[image: Main floor with addition]
[image: pre-addition]

Comment: Is this the only plan you have? With just electrical information, it will be hard to tell.

Comment: Added basement and pre-addition pics hope that helps.

Comment: It's unlikely, but I'm not sure we have everything we need here to be sure. I see no point-load footings below nor any beams specified relating to that wall. It partly depends on the floor system for the second story, though. You should bring someone on-site.

Comment: I would put $ it is load bearing with a multi story, plans don’t usually say first floor when they are a ranch. Or single story.

Comment: It appears "this wall" was an exterior wall before the addition was done. I see there's a second floor to the right in that same print, but we can't tell where the second floor aligns above the first floor. Can you tell us what's above the marked wall, and which way the trusses or floor joists (of the second floor) run?

Comment: This was an exterior wall. House is three stories including basement. Wall is on main floor with 2nd story above and basement below. I believe the floor joists for addition are perpendicular to original, not positive. Above marked wall is back wall of master walk-in.

Comment: Bringing someone on-site, should that be contractor, engineer, or architect?

Comment: If you do a search on this site you will find **many many questions about load bearing walls**. And they all have the same response, **you need an engineer to tell you for sure**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the wall can be removed, but you have several issues: 1) transfer of vertical load from second floor, 2) transfer of load to posts and footings, 3) horizontal load transfer.

1. Because the wall was originally an exterior wall, it is considered a load bearing wall, whether it has floor joists resting on the wall or not. Removing the wall will require a new beam across the opening.
2. The new beam will need to be supported on each end with posts. The connection between the posts and beam will need to be correctly selected. In addition, the posts will need a connection to the floor with approximately sized connector. You are lucky that that wall was an exterior wall, so it has an existing footing. However, depending on the load from above, the footing may need to be reinforced.
3. Exterior walls act as horizontal shear walls (whether they’re encapsulated into interior walls or not.) Removing the wall decreases the horizontal resistance. If you live in a high wind area or seismic zone, this could be a problem.

This is a structural change and therefore requires a Building Permit with adequate plans and specifications. As others have said, I’d use an architect or structural engineer (not a civil engineer) to prepare the drawings. If you’re in a hurry, ask them when they’ll be done. This is a small job for them and could sit on someone’s desk for months before finishing it. Put this key phrase in the contract “Plans and specs suitable for a Building Permit completed by ???? “